# Is there any other way to change styles than to override each of them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overriding, parent

There is really many `panel`s on my site. Each of them has a div with `items-container` class and inside of it there is a few `item` divs (all you can see in example code below). To style them all I created "global" styles (let's call them **global**) which work on all panels, but there are a few I want to have different styles.
To change the styles of `top-container` panel, I need to copy all **global** styles and override every single one of them under new selector (`top-container`).

Is there any other way to change the styles of my `top-container` panel than to override each of it separately?

JS solutions are also welcome (if there are any...).

Here is a demo: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/5nuLzg79/6/)

And here is the code:

```
<div class="top-container">
  <div class="top panel">
    <div class="items-container">
      <div class="item">Item1</div>
      <div class="item">Item2</div>
      <div class="item">Item3</div>
      <div class="item">Item4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="middle">
  <div class="left panel">
    <div class="items-container">
      <div class="item">Item1</div>
      <div class="item">Item2</div>
      <div class="item">Item3</div>
      <div class="item">Item4</div>
      <div class="item">Item5</div>
      <div class="item">Item6</div>
      <div class="item">Item7</div>
      <div class="item">Item8</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right panel">
    <div class="items-container">
      <div class="item">Item1</div>
      <div class="item">Item2</div>
      <div class="item">Item3</div>
      <div class="item">Item4</div>
      <div class="item">Item5</div>
      <div class="item">Item6</div>
      <div class="item">Item7</div>
      <div class="item">Item8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-container {
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: 50px;
}

.panel {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.items-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.top-container .items-container {
  display: block;
}

.top-container .items-container .item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I write the styles in SASS, but jsfiddle somehow didn't work even when I changed the language.

This is a simple example. I know it's not much work to change two lines of code (in this case), but my real project is much more complicated and overriding styles = hundreds of additional lines of code...

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned !

> To change the styles of top-container panel, I need to copy all global
>   styles and override every single one of them under new selector
>   (top-container).

The easiest way is to make a global class which you already did `.panel`. Now if you want to give any of panels a different style, either add a new class `<div class="top panel panel1">` or select by child selector `.middle > .left` or select by `nth-Child()`.

Here is your updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5nuLzg79/8/) with my example.

Hope it will answer your question.